# how can i compile the ts code to 'require(['somemodule'])

Tags: javascript, typescript, amd, commonjs

i'm confused if the ts export code always compile to a define call,like

```
define['somemodules',function(module1){
    //code
}]
```

i wanna get the javascript code like

```
require['somemodules',function(module1){
    //code
}]
```

so that the code will run as soon as the js file is loaded.

my tsc config

```
{
    experimentalDecorators: true,
    emitDecoratorMetadata: true,
    target: "ES5",
    module: "amd",
    emitError: false,
    outFile: filename
}
```

and my code

```
import {BaseViewModel} from '../tinyts/Core';
import {AdminService} from '../services/admin';

export class AdminModel extends BaseViewModel {

    RegisterEvents() {

    }

    OnValidateError() {

    }

    OnLoad() {
        var adminService = new AdminService();
        var data = {
            Pagesize: 10,
            Page: 1,
        }
        adminService.GetData(data, this);
    }

    LoadData(data) {
        console.log(data);

    }

}
```

**Update**
on my issue,i use the compiled javascript code in browser.so i need the amd modules.now that my compiled js file is like this:

```
define("module1",["require", "exports"],function(require,exports){
    //module1 code
}

define("module2",["require", "exports","module1"],function(require,exports,m1){
    //module2 code
}

define("module3",["require", "exports","module2"],function(require,exports,m2){
    //module3 code
    //and i want the module3 code will be executed once this file is loaded.
    var Module3 = function(){
    };
    exports.module3 = Module3;
}
```

now that i must write another script like this to execute above code

```
require(["module3"],function(m3){
    var mInstance = new m3.module3();
});
```

i have refrenced requirejs

Answer (score 1):

In your `tsconfig.json` change this line:

```
module: "amd"
```

to

```
module: "commonjs"
```

The `require()` function is part of the CommonJS specification mostly used by Node.js, so you'll have to tell the TS compiler to compile to that specification.